# Spring MVC authorization in REST resources

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, authorization

I have REST api for accessing "parties" and the URL's look like this:

```
/parties
/parties/{partyId}
```

Using Spring controllers and @PathVariable I'm able to implement this interface. But to prevent users from accessing parties they don't have access to, I have to add checks to *every* method call which is kind of repeating myself and I might forget to add it everywhere:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/parties/{partyId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Party getParty(@PathVariable Integer partyId){
    authorizeForParty(partyId);
    ...
```

Now what I would like to do is create a check that would be called every time that user enters url like this:

```
/parties/{partyId}/**
```

How would I do something like this? Do I have to create some servlet filter and parse the url myself? If I have to parse the url then is there atleast tools that would make it easy? I wish there was a way to add a method to controller that would be called before methods but could still use @PathVariables and such...

Comment: https://github.com/JamesEarlDouglas/barebones-spring-mvc/tree/master/reference/secure-rest#a-secure-restful-web-service

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how this helps at all. The examples there have the authorization done in the controller methods. I _don't_ want to do it there because I might forget it for one of them.

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up with is using the Spring MVC interceptors and parsing the path variables in the same way that Spring does. So I define an interceptor for the REST url:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/parties/*/**" />
        <bean class="PartyAuthorizationInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

The PartyAuthorizationInterceptor has to implement HandlerInterceptor in which we have to implement preHandle. It has HttpServletRequest as a parameter so we can get the request URL but we still have to parse the partyId from the url. After reading how Spring MVC does it, I found out they have a class named org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher. It can read the path variables from the URL and place the values in a map. The method is called extractUriTemplateVariables.

So the result looks like this:

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    String partyIdStr = new AntPathMatcher().extractUriTemplateVariables("/parties/{partyId}/**", request.getPathInfo()).get("partyId");
    ...
```

That makes the parsing almost as easy as using @PathVariable in MVC Controller methods. You still have to do conversions yourself(e.g. String -> Integer).

Now I can implement authorization logic on all urls that access a party in this interceptor and keep that logic out of the individual controller methods. Not as easy as I would have hoped but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Are you already using some kind of security library in your application, e. g. Spring Security?

Because the kind of logic you want to implement is a classic case for an [`AccessDecisionVoter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/AccessDecisionVoter.html) in an authentication chain. You would just put your API behind Spring Security's protection and implement the custom check as part of the security chain.

If you are not using a security framework at all, your idea of implementing a `HandlerInterceptor` may be the best alternative, though. But it would require you (as you mentioned) to take into account all kinds of obfuscation the user may use in order to gain access to other URLs (e. g. %-encoding of letters, `../../` patterns etc.).

Comment: Infact I'm using Spring Security but I only use it for authentication. I have to check the AccessDecisionVoter if it I could use it

Comment: Btw +1 for finding a solution for my requirement and not just answering my question :)